# Google Spreadsheet Addon - getElementById does not find any element

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm working on an Addon for Google Spreadsheet. I've got a screen which collects user input, and sends it to the server.

During the initialization process, I can successfully use "document.getElementById" to pre-populate several dropdowns with values from the database.

However, once the initialization is complete and the screen completely loads, none of my elements can be access using "document.getElementById" - all of them return the following error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

Obviously, in order to update the server side with client input, I need to get the form data to send to the server.

[I've attached the source code here](https://jsbin.com/qeyetucoma/edit?html,output)

P.S. I've got similar screens working flawlessly, and cannot for the life of me understand why this particular screen is failing.

**UPDATE 1**

If add the following line directly to my OnSave() function:

```
console.log("taskName: " + document.getElementById('_taskName').value);
```

I get a proper response:

```
taskName: test
```

However, If IMMEDIATELY after that I add the following line:

```
var taskName = document.getElementById('_taskName').value;
```

I get the same error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

Comment: Put all of your functions into the browsers window object.  E.g.  `function onShow() {` should be: `window.onShow = function() {`  Then add a `debugger;` line:  `window.onShow = function() {debugger;`.  That will halt the code, and you'll be able to step through the code line by line in Chrome.  Run the function that is causing the error until you find the line of code that is causing the error.  What line is it?

Comment: Is the code creating elements that are not "hard coded"?  For example, I can't find an element with an id of `_interval`.  So, obviously, you can't get a value out of an element that doesn't exist.  So, if your code is creating elements, maybe one of them isn't getting created, or isn't getting an id assigned to it.

Comment: Thanks - I've fixed all the incorrect element ID's.
However, even something like document.getElementById('_taskName').value fails - both via the code, and even in the console window if I run it myself....

Comment: Your code should be in the question.

Comment: Despite validating about 40 times, I still had one getElementByID with a non existent id....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite double and triple checking, there was still an incorrect ID name in one of the "getElementByID" functions that caused the entire object creation to fail.